# Flatten nested lists in Java

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing a complex app with Spring Boot and MongoDB. I have a `Video` class like the following. Note: All getters setters are omitted.

```
class Video{
    ObjectId _id;
    private List<OReelOCategoryLGroup> listOfReelIdCategoryIdAndGroups;
    //some other fields    
}

public class OReelOCategoryLGroup {
    ObjectId reelId;
    ObjectId categoryId;
    List<Group> groups;
}

public class Group {
    ObjectId _id;
    Boolean isMandatory=false;
    String dueDate;
}
```

I am receiving the following structure from the front-end.

```
{
    "reelId":"5eda6be5b31e96f58b3a7c65",
    "groupId":"5eda6bed217c01319701aea0",
    "category":[
        {
            "categoryId":"5eda6bf48ebcb19e031f2aa2",
            "videoId":["5eda6bff1230f45ae4b7e54a","5eda6c0464ba746e243a4d6d","5eda6c0eed64b31232bf1095"]

        },
        {
            "categoryId":"5eda6bf48ebcb19e031f2aa2",
            "videoId":["5eda6c14214ca295b6473c78"]

        }
    ]
}
```

The representation of the class is

```
public class OReelLCategoryOGroup {
    ObjectId reelId;
    ObjectId groupId;
    List<OIdOVideoId> category;

}

public class OIdOVideoId {

    ObjectId categoryId;
    List<ObjectId> videoId;

}
```

I want to update **OReelLCategoryOGroup** to each and every `videoId` what I receive from front-end. So I coded

```
public String addVideoToCurrentGroupFromAnotherReel(OReelLCategoryOGroup list) {

    Set<ObjectId> notFoundIds = new HashSet<>();

    for (OIdOVideoId cat : list.getCategory()) {

        for (ObjectId vId : cat.getVideoId()) {
            Optional<Video> video = videoRepository.findBy_id(vId);
            if (video.isPresent()) {
                Video v=video.get();

                OReelOCategoryLGroup flat = new OReelOCategoryLGroup();

                Group group = new Group();
                group.set_id(list.getGroupId());
                group.setIsMandatory(false);

                flat.setReelId(list.getReelId());
                flat.setCategoryId(cat.getCategoryId());
                flat.setGroups(Arrays.asList(group));

                v.getListOfReelIdCategoryIdAndGroups().add(flat);
                save(v);
            } else {
                notFoundIds.add(vId);
            }

        }
    }

    if (notFoundIds.size() > 0) {
        return "Few videos successfully added to group, but " + notFoundIds.toString() + " are not found in database";
    }
    return "Videos successfully added to group";
}
```

Here the complicity is \$O(n^2)\$. But if `listOfReelIdCategoryIdAndGroups` contains `reelId == list.getReelId() && categoryId == cat.getCategoryId()` then I have to add the **group** to that list of groups. If I'm going to check it, there will be another loop inside the nested loop. So complexity is \$O(n^3)\$.

```
for (OIdOVideoId cat : list.getCategory()) {
    for (ObjectId vId : cat.getVideoId()) {
        if (video.isPresent()) {

            for(OReelOCategoryLGroup g:v.getListOfReelIdCategoryIdAndGroups()){
                if(g.getReelId()==list.getReelId() && g.getCategoryId()==cat.getCategoryId()){
                    g.getGroups().add(group);
                }else{
                    // insert
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel this is inefficient. Is there any way to overcome to this problem with Java 8, Stream API?

Comment: I suggest you merge all your code blocks into one. This has two benefits ① The description is easier to read ② The code is easier to copy and improve.